# H2O XGBoost on Windows: Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostJNI.XGDMatrixCreateFromCSREx([J[I[FI[J)I

Tags: r, windows, xgboost, h2o

When I try to run XGboost in R on Windows 7 and on Windows Server 2008R2 via `h2o.xgboost()` with H2O **3.12.01** I get the following error:

> Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostJNI.XGDMatrixCreateFromCSREx([J[I[FI[J)I

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
h2o.no_progress() # Don't show progress bars in RMarkdown output

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into H2O
train <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
test <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_test_5k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
y <- "response"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])
test[,y] <- as.factor(test[,y])

# Number of CV folds (to generate level-one data for stacking)
nfolds <- 5

# Train & Cross-validate a (shallow) XGB-GBM
my_xgb1 <- h2o.xgboost(x = x,
                       y = y,
                       training_frame = train,
                       distribution = "bernoulli",
                       ntrees = 50,
                       max_depth = 3,
                       min_rows = 2,
                       learn_rate = 0.2,
                       nfolds = nfolds,
                       fold_assignment = "Modulo",
                       keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                       seed = 1)
```

> ```
> R version 3.4.0 Patched (2017-05-19 r72713)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] h2o_3.12.0.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0    RCurl_1.95-4.8 jsonlite_1.5   bitops_1.0-6
> ```

3.12.01 was the newest development version linked on the h2o.ai homepage, which I upgraded to after not finding this function in 3.10. However, a comment by @MarcoSandri indicated there's a newer development version (3.13) on their Amazon AWS, so downloaded it and upgraded the cluster and R package accordingly.

The upgrade from 3.12 to 3.13 seemed to go smoothly, until I attempted to use the `h2o.xgboost()` function. Then it threw a different error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  :
```

> ```
> ERROR MESSAGE:
>
> -1
>
> Error in fetch(key) : 
>   lazy-load database 'E:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0patched/library/h2o/help/h2o.rdb' is corrupt
> ```

Comment: Please, post `sessionInfo()` and `java -version`. Try to install the latest h2o version available here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3943/index.html?aliId=2972522 (there is an R package inside)

Comment: @MarcoSandri Sure, this is version 3.12.01. Their website says that's the latest bleeding edge development version, but I see from your link that they're already working on a 3.13 even though the official release is still only 3.9. I'll go ahead and give that a try, thank you.

Comment: @MarcoSandri I finished upgrading to 3.13 for both the cluster and the R package, but now it's throwing a different error. I will update my question.

Comment: I understand. I asked you to update the package just because `h2o.xgboost` generated a different error on my Windows 7 PC. I can see that now we have the same error. I am trying to find a solution to the problem. I will contact you if I found something interesting.

Comment: There is no native windows support yet for xgboost in H2O as of July 1, 2017 (so preview release 3.12.0.1 and stable release 3.10.5.3).

Comment: I've seen the lazy-load database failure related to RStudio.  Try restarting RStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is not supported with H2O-3 XGBoost. For reference, here is a list of OS's supported by H2O-3 XGBoost:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#limitations

Comment: I get the same error today - on Window 10 Desktop: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4983